# What's the circle piece in this MOC?

Tags: part-identification, moc

I saw a moc from [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legocy/16359474006/).

[image]

But have no idea what the piece it use on the arms of the robot, and on the guns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [Tile 1 x 1 Round, with groove](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=98138)

[image: Tile 1 x 1 Round, with groove]

Edit after clarification in the question:

The arms have something that looks like a bit of [Hose, Ribbed](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=78c02) cut to the required size.

The gun is, as gev pointed out, based on a standalone [ray gun piece](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=13608) that has the ribbed section molded in originally.

[image: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=13608]

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear first. Maybe new picture will help?

Comment: I am not so sure about it, but could it be flex hose cut to size? http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=78c02 You should probably ask the creator directly :)

Comment: You can see the cut hose technique in other MOCs in the series, especially [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legocy/16384530492/in/photostream/) and [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/legocy/16197822918/in/photostream/)

Answer (score 5):

The bit held in the mech hand is a [Ray gun](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=ray%20gun).

The bit on the forearms is almost certainly a short bit of [Hose, Ribbed 7mm D. 2L](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=78c02) like zovits said.